# Pug HTML tags being greyed out

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I'm trying to make my webserver output a simple html page.
I'm able to write to the document OK., but when it writes specific tags (head, script) it outputs them as greyed out versions even though I never set "enabled" to false

I'm certain I'm accessing my server info properly, I think its an issue in how I'm rendering the pug file. Any suggestions would be appreciated

```
doctype html
html
    head#head       
        script 
    body#body
        select#restaurant-select
        br
        br
        div#info
        div#main
            div(class="column-left")
            div(class="column-middle")
                p= aragorn
                p= legolas
                p= frodo
            div(class="column-right")
```

Comment: What does it mean *greyed out*?

Comment: What is the actual code rendered when you do a "View Source" in the browser?  Also note that there are zero reasons to use id properties for the `head` and `body` elements, just leave them as `<head>` and `<body>`.

Answer (score 2):

The `head` and `script` elements don't generate output. `head` contains metadata and/or scripts, that's why they appear greyed out in the developer tools Inspector (if that's what you mean as greyed out).